# How to completely hide the *last page* in a Word document, when the penultimate page has a different orientation?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, printing, templates

I have a template document in MS Word, which includes instructions on the first page. I have formatted this entire section with hidden text, such that it does not print. Users fill in the document, and when they print or export a PDF, the first page is completely ignored. There is the slight caveat that the Header/Footer from the first hidden section will be shown on the 'new first page', but I can put the header I want on page 2 in on page 1 to fix this So far, so good.

**How can I replicate this functionality with the last page?**

No matter what I do, there is always a 'blank' page printed at the end of the document - I can get the *content* of the page to vanish, but the page itself always remains.

As @Yokki points out, you *can* get the last page to disappear by also making the section break on the penultimate page hidden - but this has the effect of then applying the page format from the final hidden section to the 'new last page' (in a similar manner to that of the header/footer from the first section)

In the image below, I have made a 'demo' document. The goal is to get only Pages 2 and 3 to print.

[image: Document Setup - 2 and 3 only desired to print]

If I simply hide everything on PAGE 1 (except the header and footer, which will jump to Page 2), and everything on PAGE 4 (including the header and footer), then I get this:

[image: Blank Page Visible]

Hiding the section break on Page 3 as well prints the correct number of pages, but also reverts Page 3 to being Portrait

[image: Incorrect orientation]

(Hidden text is set to be visible by default using group policy, so that users can see the instructions!)

Comment: If you place your cursor right after the last visible character in your next-to-last page and press Delete several times, you last page should disappear altoghether. Your document will be one page shorter.

Comment: Hi @Didier - this is not the problem - I need the last page to exist, just to not print!

Comment: I should have known it wasn't that simple... :-) Let me think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a problem if you have, for example, any footnotes or endnotes that are set up to display at the end of the section/document, but other than that, I would do it by

- inserting a Page Break before your text (Don't try to rely on automatic page breaking)
- selecting the page break and all the following text (except perhaps the final paragraph mark in the document, and marking it as Hidden.

Comment: This is the process that I have followed already - the problem is, this only works if the last page is formatted exactly the same way, since hiding the section break effectively puts the text from the penultimate page into the final pages formatting. I will update my question to make things clearer

Comment: Yes, that certainly creates a problem! Personally, I think I would just accept that the final page would have to have the same layout characteristics as the penultimate page and use a page break.

Comment: Agreed that makes sense - but... the final page needs to be the same as the *antepenultimate* page, so you can delete the landscape page at the end easily by removing the content of the last two pages / the third last page then inherits the footer and orientation etc. from the original last page.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift: not really with you there (too many interacting possibilities already, really. Using a page break instead of a section break seemed OK here). But since *you* know what you need to test, another thing to explore would be to use a section break before the final page, but put it inside an IF field like this: { IF 0 = 1 "<the section break>" } (where the {} are the special ctrl-F9 field braces). Then when the hidden text is visible, you see the final page in whatever layout you give that final section. No idea if that might help or not, really.

Comment: Holy crap - you can use logical statements like that? 

Comment: you’re right - it might not be helpful here but I can think of plenty of other places it might! Let me get testing

Comment: Yes, you can use { IF <condition> "<true-result" "false-result" } with pretty much anything in the two result branches, but with various limitations (and ambiguities. Can confuse the users, too. Probably not a good idea to use it for conditional breaks except in exceptional cases!

Comment: This didn't fix my specific issue, but I'm marking as the correct answer to give the reputation boost - because this was the closest by far, and is correct for all situations except when you have a penultimate landscape page with final and ante-penultimate portrait.

Answer (score 0):

This problem sometimes occur out of the blue and for no apparent reasons. Normally, Microsoft Word should remove the last page when there is no text, but it doesn't in some cases.

I have experienced this multiple times. So, here is a solution that should work for you -

Here, is a blank page that is not going even after deleting everything from that page:

[image]

I need to get rid of this right away, else this's gonna be printed along with the first page. Now go to 'home' tab and click on  ¶ to see something like this:

[image]

(**note**: I have got a lot of ¶ in the second page while replicating this problem. You might get just one or two)

Now go to 'view' tab and select 'Draft' as shown:

[image]

Scroll down to the last page you want to remove. Each page in this 'Draft' mode is separated by a thin ------------ line, just like this:

[image]

Select every ¶ symbol from *below that last thin line* and hit '**delete**'

**That's it.**
Now, in the 'view' tab, click on 'Print Layout'. You will be taken to the layout with which we are most familiar, I mean this:

[image]

Now, click on the 'Home' tab. It's time to remove all those ¶ symbols. For this, just 'Unmark' ¶:

[image]

***Voila,*** the annoying last page is gone now:

[image]

Save the document in desired format and try giving a print command. Last empty page shouldn't be printed now, because there is none :)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Sanu_012 - Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this is not my problem - I need the last page to exist, and have content in it, but I do not want it to print. See my updated question with screenshots for more details!

Comment: that can be achieved by giving print command manually to those pages. Isn't it? like this: https://helpx.adobe.com/in/acrobat/kb/print-selected-pages-acrobat-reader.html or this https://word.tips.net/T001065_Printing_Only_Selected_Pages.html

Comment: Yes and no - this is for a document template that will be used by users with little experience, and needs to be 'foolproof' if possible - i.e. if they just click "export as PDF", the output needs to be correct. Without installing a PDF printer, or using additional steps to remove the blank page, this won't work...